# Handing back different objects from the one VB.Net function

Tags: c#, json, vb.net

Context: Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7

I'm in the process of porting [VBJSON](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) to VB.Net. If some enterprising soul has already done this, please let me know and spare me the agony.

Anyway, I was wanting to return from a function either a Dictionary or a List. Ordinarily, I suppose, one would pass back an Object however that's giving me grief where I have a List embedded in a Dictionary or a Dictionary embedded in a List or one of the other possible combinations feasible with JSON. I can't simply go from

```
var result = JSON.parse("{'collection':['dog','cat',2,3]}");
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(result["collection"][1]);
```

without doing a lot of casting of Object to either List or Dictionary or some combination thereof. So I'm casting around for ideas, trying to figure out how to get the parse function, which is called recursively by the way, to return something other than a generic Object.

Comment: I think generics is what you want here - 'parse' would have a generic type parameter which would be the type of the single parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a port of that specific library? If not, there are already JSON libraries for .NET, including [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). It's also possible to [serialize and deserialize to JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Dictionary and List both implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `ICollection<T>`, so your parse method could return one of those types and pass back either a list or a dictionary. That would be a little more type-specific than `Object`. You would still be able to iterate through the return value, but your `Console.WriteLine(result["collection"][3]);` still won't work.

Instead of returning either a List or a Dictionary, could you simply always return an [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It preserves its original order, so you could lookup by index or by key.

Comment: I know about the various JSON libraries for .NET. My problem stems from trying to use the Newtonsoft one in SQL server: it can be done but not without a lot of serious hoop through-jumping.